# How do I send the latest message ID with Express?

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js

I have the following code and when I run it I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
```

I'm on discord.js v12.0.2 and express v4.16.2
This is my code:

```
app.get("/last", function(req, res) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")

  res.send(String(client.channels.cache.get('540281078213246998').messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).messages.first().id))
})
```

I'm trying to get the last message's ID in my Discord channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`MessageManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) it returns a Promise that resolved with either a [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) or a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of messages; that means that you have to:

- Wait for the Promise to be fulfilled
- Check whether a Collection has been returned (which should never happen in your case, but I'll cover it anyway)
- Get the ID from the message

Here's how I would approach this:

```js
client.channels.cache.get('540281078213246998').messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(msg => {
  if (msg instanceof Map) // If the function returned a Collection...
    msg = msg.first() // ...set it to the first value.

  res.send(msg.id)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to solve,
[messageCollection#fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns promise, so you need to put there await or use .then function.